# How to deploy nodejs + angular app to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform

I have a nodejs backend and an angular frontend app in the same folder. The angular app outputs the build files to a static folder and nodejs uses the following to load the html file

```
//Idiomatic expression in express to route and respond to a client request
app.get('/', (req, res) => {        //get requests to the root ("/") will route here
    res.sendFile(process.cwd()+"/angularApp/static/index.html")      //server responds by sending the index.html file to the client's browser
                                                        //the .sendFile method needs the absolute path to the file, see: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile 
});
```

This is my app.yaml for nodejs :

```
    runtime: nodejs16
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: angularApp/static/index.html
  upload: angularApp/static/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: angularApp/static
```

However when I deploy the app to GCP I get the following errors in the console

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

What should the app.yaml file contain?

Answer (score 0):

Tou can take a look of how docker works. Basically, you put your dependencies and source code into an image, then you ca easily deploy it on google cloud platform https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying .

Comment: Is there any other way apart from this? I am not able to use Docker for this

Comment: You can create a virtual machine https://cloud.google.com/compute . There you can ssh into your instance, install your dependencies manually, then you can start your server exacly like you do locally.